# dplyr include individual line items [rows], after group() and summarise() - possible?

Tags: r, dplyr

The following code groups mtcars by cylinder and counts how many line items there are for each cylinder class.

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(count = n())

cyl count
4 11
6 7
8 14
```

I'd like dplyr to spit out the horsepower (hp) for each of the cylinder classes, directly under the summarised line items. The head() would look somthing like:

```
cyl count
4 11
(indent) 52 <- individual hp value for first 4 cyl line item
(indent) 62 <- individual hp value for second 4 cyl line item
(indent) 65 <- individual hp value for third 4 cyl line item
(indent) 66 <- individual hp value for fourth 4 cyl line item
.
.
6 7
(indent) 105 <- individual hp value for first 6 cyl line item
(indent) 110 <- individual hp value for second 6 cyl line item
etc.
```

Is this possible? I ask rhetorically, of course it is, I just don't know how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can print what you want through `summarize`, but it can't return `NULL`, so you can wrap it in curly braces and return `NA`:

```
mtcars %>%
  add_count(cyl) %>%
  select(hp,cyl,n) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarize({cat(cyl[1],n[1],"\n",paste("    ",hp,"\n"));NA}) %>%
  invisible

4 11 
      93 
      62 
      95 
      66 
      52 
      65 
      97 
      66 
      91 
      113 
      109 
6 7 
      110 
      110 
      110 
      105 
      123 
      123 
      175 
8 14 
      175 
      245 
      180 
      180 
      180 
      205 
      215 
      230 
      150 
      150 
      245 
      175 
      264 
      335
```

Comment: Is there a way to store that in a data frame? When I try it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: I understood that you were asking for a specific format to print on the console, as you mention indentation. I don't understand what data.frame you would like, you mean a 3 column data.frame with a bunch of empty cells ? What are you going to do with this object ?

Comment: Your answer is correct and I'd just assume leave it that way. Maybe you can put this secondary response as a comment. So yes - I would like to know how to print the individual `hp` values under their respective summaries. The indent is not needed. EG > Line 1 equal to "4, 11". Line 2 equal to "93". Line 3 equal to "62". And so on.

Comment: In a `data.frame` lines need the same amount of element, it's still not clear to me if you want one column data.frame containing strings (or vectors, or lists), in which the first element would be "4, 11" , or if you want a two column `data.frame` with 2nd column mostly empty. If it's a separate question from the one you asked here you should ask it separately with a precise reproducible example and expected output so we can help better and it's more useful to future readers.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. My new request does warrant a separate, different question. I am looking for the latter "two column `data.frame` with 2nd column mostly empty. I'll dig around Stack Overflow before asking the question to make sure it's not a duplicate. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite in the format you want, but this is basically the same information?
Add a marker for the count of `cyl` and then arrange the rows by `hp`. `add_count` is just a wrapper for `group_by` then `mutate(n())`.

```r
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  add_count(cyl) %>%
  arrange(cyl, hp) %>%
  select(cyl, n, hp)
#> # A tibble: 32 x 3
#>      cyl     n    hp
#>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#>  1  4.00    11  52.0
#>  2  4.00    11  62.0
#>  3  4.00    11  65.0
#>  4  4.00    11  66.0
#>  5  4.00    11  66.0
#>  6  4.00    11  91.0
#>  7  4.00    11  93.0
#>  8  4.00    11  95.0
#>  9  4.00    11  97.0
#> 10  4.00    11 109  
#> # ... with 22 more rows
```

Created on 2018-02-23 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).